ZFC construction of tuple-based cartesian product for arbitrary finite number
Question:
Can the finite, tuple-based Cartesian product of sets be defined for an arbitrary number of sets, using only sets and NOT relying on classes or other non-existing non-set objects in ZFC?
Key definitions:
By a tuple of length 2 here and below, I mean the standard ordered pair $(a, b) = \{\{a\}, \{a, b\}\}$.
By tuples of length k + 1 , where $tp_k$ are the first k components of the tuple (the tuple of length k) and v is the last element, I mean ordered pair $(tp_k, v)$.
What I Understand:
I understand how to define $A \times B$ using ZFC axioms.
I also understand how to define the tuple-based Cartesian product for a specified, fixed finite number of sets, such as $(A \times B) \times C$, $((A \times B) \times C) \times D$, and so on. But I am looking for a definition for an arbitrary number of sets in the product, and I wonder if such a definition is possible within ZFC.
What I Am Not Asking:
I am NOT asking about defining the product as a set of functions (e.g., as in $\{f \in (⋃ A_i)^I | \forall i \in I, f(i) \in A_i\}$, where $I = n = \{k \in \mathbb{N} | k < n\}$).This would define the product as a set of functions, not as a set of ordered tuples, and I am specifically interested in defining the arbitrary finite Cartesian product in terms of tuples.
The Precise Problem:
I am asking for the correct definition that uses ZFC axioms and theorems to construct a valid existing unique object.

I am NOT asking for just a simple equation declaring the desired inductive recurrence relation, which is the trivial part of the question.
For instance, if we want to define a sequence of finite Cartesian powers using the recurrence relation $A^{0} = \{\varnothing\}$, $A^{1} = A$, $A^{n + 2} = A^{n + 1} \times A$, the good question is, can this sequence be constructed inductively within ZFC?
The declared recurrence relation itself does not guarantee this.

For example, in some theorem proofs, there are explicit constructions of recursive functions. These constructions may involve unions to join functions, restricted to some initial segment of the natural numbers. The resulting construction is then proven to be a correctly defined recursive function.
Context:
Statements about recursion on natural numbers in set theory often require mappings to some larger fixed set, while theorems about inductive definitions require a specified universe (or fixed superset) to contain all the inductively defined subsets.
I’m concerned that defining a Cartesian product of arbitrary finite length as a set of ordered tuples might not be possible in ZFC. I haven't been able to devise an approach similar to the one mentioned in the previous paragraph.
The definition I’m looking for should be well-defined within ZFC and must NOT rely on a set of all sets or other non-set objects.
My Concern:
I have been puzzled by the fact that I cannot find a straightforward way to define finite arbitrary-length Cartesian products of sets in ZFC as a set of tuples. The idea that such a seemingly simple construction — finite tuple-based Cartesian products of arbitrary length might NOT be definable within a most common foundation of mathematics is something I find quite surprising.

I think this question would benefit significantly from removing the emphasis on what you're not asking for, and adding more clarity about what you are asking for. For example, it's an easy application of the set-theoretic recursion theorem (which is itself an easy application of $\mathsf{Replacement}$) to construct, for each set $A$, the set ${\langle n,A^n\rangle: n\in\omega}$. Is this sufficient for you?

In particular, you write "The declared recurrence relation itself does not guarantee this." But it does, via the recursion theorem. So, what exactly are you asking for here?

The recursion theorem requires some set X such that f is a function $\mathbb{N} \to X$. Why does such set exist?

For the first comment: I am asking for $\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n} A_i$ construction, where ${A_i}{i \in [1, n+1){\mathbb{N}}}$ is indexed family set. And in particular, $A^n$ construction in ZFC. Naive application of recursion theorem will not work, because I doubt that mapping f is not in fact well-defined due to the fact that its range may be not a set in ZFC.

In the question I just wanted to reduce the number of replies with cartesian product as functions, just declarations of recurrent relation without proving that there exists such set, the replies that use something that is not well-defined in ZFC. In particular, in your second response, how are you justifying that for any A such function f that works as follows: $f(B) = B \times A$ exists, what will be its domain and range, if it should be applicable to any $A^n$ to return $A^{n+1}$. Why its domain and range are valid sets?

The wikipedia article actually states the recursion theorem in a weaker form than is available. But here's one way to construct $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ - or more precisely, $\{\langle n, A^n\rangle:n\in\omega\}$ - directly using the axiom of replacement (I've heard this called the "sequence-coding trick," and it gets used all over the place):
Let $\varphi(w,x,y,z)$ be the formula asserting the following:

$y$ is an ordinal $<\omega$.

$x$ is a function (= appropriate set of ordered pairs) with domain $y+1\setminus\{0\}$.

$x(1)=z$ and, for each $n<y$, we have $x(n+1)=x(n)\times z$.

$x(y)=w$.


Intuitively, $\varphi(w,x,y,z)$ says "$w=z^y$ as witnessed by $x$." By induction, $\mathsf{ZF}$ proves $$\forall z\forall y\in\omega\exists!w\exists x\varphi(w,x,y,z)$$ (here "$\exists!$" is the unique-existence quantifier). Now for any set $a$, replacement to the formula-with-parameter $$\theta(y;a)\equiv\exists x\exists y[\varphi(w,x,y,a)]$$ yields the set $\{a^n:n\in\omega\}$; applying replacement to the slightly different formula-with-parameter $$\psi(w;a)\equiv\exists x\exists v\exists y[w=\langle y,v\rangle\wedge \varphi(w,x,y,a)]$$ yields the set $\{\langle n, a^n\rangle:n\in\omega\}$. Note that the only "sethood hypothesis" needed to invoke replacement is that the domain - here $\omega$ - be a set; the whole point of replacement is that you can use it when you don't know that the codomain is a set yet.

Thank you very much! Looks like I approximately got it. We first built a formula that states, what we need. Then we use simple induction to prove it for any natural number. And because we proved that some predicate is "functional", we can apply replacement axiom. That is interesting application of it. By the way, the wikipedia says that constructing $A^n$ with other axioms, but without remplacement is impossible. Looks like finite cartesian product (where sets may be different) may be constructed with a similiar idea.

As I understand, maybe we can add another quantifier, that states that there exists such B that x is a function $ y+1 \setminus {0} \to B$ and prove it together with everything else in induction
